# How to make the cell height fit the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and there are 10 rows (This is a dynamic table, so more rows will be loaded).

Each cell/row should have the height of the full screen. There are different screen sizes in iOS now.

Therefore i am not able to give a fixed height for cell row as iOS devices have varying heights.

So how can I make a cell height to fit the screen height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `tableView` is in a ViewController then you can use this code below:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
}
```

Else if your screen covers full screen, then use this

```
return CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]);
```

Else if your screen contains a Navigation Bar as well, then use

```
return CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] - 64.0f);
```

**Or the Best Solution would be perhaps**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return CGRectGetHeight(tableView.bounds);
}
```

**Edited**

Its better to use `rowHeight` property instead of the `delegate`. Reason discussed below:

> There are performance implications to using
>   `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `rowHeight`. Every
>   time a table view is displayed, it calls
>   `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on the delegate for each of its
>   rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table
>   views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

Thanks to [rdelmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar)

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight)

Comment: In the first case, you need to pass `self.view.bounds` instead of just `self.view`

Comment: It's more efficient to set the rowHeight property instead of using heightForRowAtIndexPath if all the rows have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.view.frame.size.height-yourTableViewStartingYPosition;
}
```

If it's full screen it will be `return self.view.frame.size.height`